# HC-05 receives only first few bytes

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I have an android device and stm32f103 + HC-05 bt dongle. I'm sending 10 bytes "0123456789" string from android to stm32, but I'm receiving only random 1-5 bytes. code on stm32 side:

```
long received = 0;
const unsigned long buffer_size = 128;
uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];

void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}

[...]
void loop() {
    [...]
    if(Serial1.available()){
        received += Serial1.readBytes(buffer + received, bufferSize-received);
    }    
}
```

So, if will send "0123456789" from android, let say, 3 times every 1 second, on stm32 i will receive 3 portions like this:

"0", "0567", "047"

or something like this, i.e. I always receive first byte and it's always correct, but it looks like the rest bytes could be randomly lost.

any idea what am I doing wrong?

P.S.> On stm32 side I'm using [Arduino STM32 library](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32). Serial1 is a UART interface, which is located on stm32f103's PA9 and PA10 pins.

I tried to use other bod rate (19200, 38400), but in this case the data is completely corrupted, i.e. just random bytes.

When I'm sending data from stm32 to Android everything works just fine, i.e. I'm receiving all the data on android side.

I'm using standard BluetoothSocket on android side. So, code looks like this:

```
BluetoothSocket socket;
OutputStream outStream;
[...]

void init(...) {
    socket = ConnectToSTM32(...);
    [...]
    outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
}

void send(byte[] bytes) {
    outStream.write(bytes);
}

[...]
String strToSend = "0123456789";
send(strToSend.getBytes());
```

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code we can't help you. There's nothing obviously wrong from that snippet, so the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed without the rest of the code we can't tell, but I bet £1 you're assuming that all the data will arrive in one lump and that when `Serial1.available()` returns `false` you've got it all, which is a bad assumption. Still, edit the question so that it's useful for others.

Comment: Have you set values to your HC-05? Meaning changing the rate? Android send data at about 115200 bauds. So if you try to receive them at 9600 and display at this speed, this can explain whay's happening. Also, on Android side, performing a Log("info") must be a good idea to be really sure of what you send. Also, from where came "Serial1"?

Comment: @Majenko Added some extra details

Comment: @MarkSmith I don't assume anything - I just read available data from Serial1. I don't know how many bytes are available - just read them all and write this data continuously to a buffer

Comment: @Peter I've added some extra information. I've tried to use different speed, but not 115200 - will try it today. I didn't find any information how can I setup bluetooth speed on android side (actually, I thought it should be negotiated automatically). What exactly can I log to ensure of what I'm sending? I use Java OutputStream's write method to send data.

Comment: I think you'll get much better quality help if you post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @MarkSmith Will do it today, but I doubt you could repro it because of hardware specific. I suspect that problem is on android side and it, probably, related to stm32 serial stream implementation.

Comment: @Tutankhamen I've found nothing on Android to set Bluetooth speed. My App use it at 115200 as it seems to be the "basic speed". The problem came from from the fact this speed is not avaible with the SerialSoftware lib  on the Arduino (higher than 19500, the lib start to loose bits). On Arduino I use the basic RX and TX pin with Serial.begin(115200).

Comment: @Tutankhamen Contact me via my profil and I'll send you the Android code from my App, for Bluetooth. Maybe this would help;

Comment: @Peter I don't think there is a way to send private message in StackExchange

Comment: Just tried the same code with the same HC-05 module, but with Arduino Nano - everything works just perfect

Comment: Try adding a delay (10) inside if (serial1.available())

Comment: @MITURAJ For what?

Comment: Cz UART data reception is slower than microcontroller execution

Comment: And how delay could help? The logic now is: if (data_available) read_data();

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901058/arduino-cant-read-serial-properly

Comment: @MITURAJ It shouldn't work like this, but anyway it's not the case. I'm polling data from the local buffer, not from remote device.

Comment: So, the problem was in disabled interrupts. I just remove a library which is forcibly disabling interrupts and everything is working now.

Comment: Okay. You have not posted the full code. So we can only assume based on current code snipping.